# Como unir o retorno de 8 query's em uma só?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tenho 8 query's  todas tem 5 colunas incomuns e algumas colunas distintas,
 Com base nas colunas comuns eu consigo exibir um único resultado das 8?

Campos em comum:

```
F.CHAPA     AS  CHAPA,
F.NOME      AS  NOME,
F.FILIAL    AS  FILIAL,
F.SECAO     AS  SECAO,
F.SITUACAO  AS  SITUACAO,
```

Comment: Coloca o que você já fez.

Comment: Como assim ? todas as consultas ?

Comment: Em todas as consultas, há linhas para os mesmos valores de CHAPA? Isto é, se há uma relação 1:1 entre cada uma das consultas.

Comment: Sim,Tem chapa em todas.

Comment: Não serve um simples UNION? `SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM tabela1 UNION SELECT campo1, campo2, campo3 FROM tabela2 UNION...` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é transformar cada consulta em uma CTE e então juntar o resultado das 8 consultas. Deve-se retirar o ORDER BY ao inserir o código de cada consulta como CTE.

```
-- código #1  
with
Consulta1 as (
  ... insira aqui o código da primeira consulta
),

Consulta2 as (
  ... insira aqui o código da segunda consulta
),

  ...

Consulta8 as (
  ... insira aqui o código da oitava consulta
)

-- reúne o resultado das 8 consultas, agrupando-as pelo valor de CHAPA
SELECT C1.CHAPA, C1.NOME, C1.FILIAL, C1.SECAO, C1.SITUACAO,
       C2.colunas não comuns,
       ...
       C8.colunas não comuns
  from Consulta1 as C1
       inner join Consulta2 as C2 on C2.CHAPA = C1.CHAPA
       ...
       inner join Consulta8 as C8 on C8.CHAPA = C1.CHAPA
  where ...
  order by ... ;
```

---

Outra possibilidade é armazenar o resultado de cada consulta em tabelas temporárias e após fazer a junção.

```
-- código #2
-- apaga tabelas temporárias (possível erro em execução anterior)
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#Consulta1', 'U') is not null 
  DROP TABLE #Consulta1;
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#Consulta2', 'U') is not null 
  DROP TABLE #Consulta2;
...
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#Consulta8', 'U') is not null 
  DROP TABLE #Consulta8;
go

-- executa consulta #1
   ... inserir código da consulta 1, acrescentando
          into #Consulta1
       imediatamente antes da cláusula FROM
go

-- executa consulta #2
   ... inserir código da consulta 2, acrescentando
          into #Consulta2
       imediatamente antes da cláusula FROM
go

...


-- executa consulta #8
   ... inserir código da consulta 8, acrescentando
          into #Consulta8
       imediatamente antes da cláusula FROM
go

-- reúne o resultado das 8 tabelas temporárias
SELECT C1.CHAPA, C1.NOME, C1.FILIAL, C1.SECAO, C1.SITUACAO,
       C2.colunas não comuns,
       ...
       C8.colunas não comuns
  from #Consulta1 as C1
       inner join #Consulta2 as C2 on C2.CHAPA = C1.CHAPA
       ...
       inner join #Consulta8 as C8 on C8.CHAPA = C1.CHAPA
  where ...
  order by ... ;
go

-- apaga tabelas temporárias
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#Consulta1', 'U') is not null 
  DROP TABLE #Consulta1;
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#Consulta2', 'U') is not null 
  DROP TABLE #Consulta2;
...
IF Object_ID('tempDB..#Consulta8', 'U') is not null 
  DROP TABLE #Consulta8;
go
```

O código #2 pode ser otimizado, com a criação de índice pela coluna CHAPA em cada tabela temporária, mas é preciso avaliar localmente se compensa.

---

Mas a melhor forma mesmo é reescrever as consultas, tentando agrupá-las em uma única ou no menor número de consultas possível, de modo a reduzir o I/O nas tabelas.

Comment: Demorei porque estava validando,era isso mesmo,Obrigado!

Comment: Concordo,vou tentar reescreva-las em um outro momento,Obrigado!